# How to implement default method like StringCollection and some class does?

Tags: c#, .net

While answering a question i came upon this

```
StringCollection sc = new StringCollection();

sc.Add("Foo");
```

But this can be written as

```
StringCollection sc = new StringCollection() {"Foo"};
```

and this cannot be written

```
StringCollection sc = new StringCollection() {new string[] {"Foo"} };
```

That means `Add` method is called and `AddRange` is not.

How can i make a class that can have this functionality of having a default method called while creating its object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called a [Collection Initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx). The class must implement [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) and have a public `Add` method.

The class can have multiple `Add` methods, e.g.

```
public class MyCollection : IEnumerable
{
    public void Add(string item) { ... }

    public void Add(string[] items) { ... }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I think he meant in general, and not a Collection.

Comment: There are Object Initializers, which initialize the properties of an object, and Collection Initializers, which require that the class implements IEnumerable and which call the Add method. There are no other, more general constructs in C#. The method that is automatically called when an object is initialized is called constructor :-)

Comment: @rikitikitik: Exactly. In general not particular for Collection.

Comment: @dtb: Can this be done only with Collections and not with any other class of my own that do not implement `IEnumerable`

Comment: As stated above, you have the choice between Object and Collection Initializers. Collection Initializers cannot be done without implementing IEnumerable and having an Add method.

Answer (score 2):

The code is a collection initializer : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

> Collection initializers let you specify one or more element
>   intializers when you initialize a collection class that implements
>   IEnumerable. The element initializers can be a simple value, an
>   expression or an object initializer. By using a collection initializer
>   you do not have to specify multiple calls to the Add method of the
>   class in your source code; the compiler adds the calls.

The call to "Add" is generated by the compiler. So unless you write your own C# compiler, you cannot customize the behavior to call "AddRange".